# Catch-all subdomains email

Tags: email, email-server, mx-record, wildcard-subdomain

I want to catch all emails sent to `* @ *.domain.com` to a single account, how do I do that?

I've already set up a wildcard MX record, and it resolves correctly. But I'm having trouble finding any email-server software capable of this.

PS. I'd prefer a hosted/web-based solution, or a Windows solution, since our farm is built around Windows-servers... But a *nix option is also fine :(

PPS. Google Apps cant' do that, tried it...

Comment: you will get lots of lots of spam.

Comment: Did you try to hire **real** postmaster? Any MTA can be used really for this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this blog post with detailed instructions for Postfix, thanks to Frank by showing the path:

http://www.myintervals.com/blog/2011/07/14/configure-your-web-based-application-to-receive-email-using-wildcard-virtual-subdomains-postfix-and-linux/

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, postfix can do this .

Here is the solution presented in this article, that how Postfix setup can catch-all email accounts using /etc/postfix/virtual

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-postfix-catch-all-email-accounts/

Comment: Thanks for showing the way! I'm +ing your answer, but will add my own since I found more detailed instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Windows MTA with web-interface of Administration, which can handle catch-all - [Axigen](http://www.axigen.com/knowledgebase/How-to-set-up-a-catchall-account_177.html)